# Moment of inertia of an ellipse in 2D

Tags: integration, conic-sections, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to compute the moment of inertia of a 2D ellipse about the z axis, centered on the origin, with major/minor axes aligned to the x and y axes.  My best guess was to try to compute it as:

$$4\rho \int_0^a \int_0^{\sqrt{b^2(1 - x^2/a^2)}}(x^2 +y^2)\,dydx$$

... I couldn't figure out how to integrate that.  Is there a better way or a trick, or is the formula known?  I'd also be happy with a good numerical approximation given a and b.

Comment: Did you try polar coordinates?

Comment: Equivalently, if you work out the moment of inertia tensor of a circle, you should be able to get the one for an ellipse by a linear transformation of coordinates.

Comment: @Sam: It is not at all clear to me how you can use the formula for a circle to generate the formula for an ellipse. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use 'polar' coordinates, as in $\phi(\lambda, \theta) = (\lambda a \cos \theta, \lambda b \sin \theta)$, with $(\lambda, \theta) \in S = (0,1] \times [0,2 \pi]$. It is straightforward to compute the Jacobian determinant as

$$ J_{\phi}(\lambda, \theta) = |\det D\phi(\lambda, \theta)| = \lambda a b.$$

Let $E = \{ (x,y) \,|\, 0 <(\frac{x}{a})^2 + (\frac{y}{b})^2 \leq 1 \}$. (Eliminating $(0,0)$ makes no difference to the integral, and is a technicality for the change of variables below.) We have $E = \phi (S)$, and

$$\begin{align}
I &= \rho \int_{\phi ( S)} (x^2+y^2) \, dx dy \\
&= \rho \int_{S} \lambda^2 (a^2 \cos^2 \theta+ b^2 \sin^2 \theta) \lambda a b \, d \lambda d \theta \\
&= \rho a b \int_{0}^1 \lambda^3 \, d \lambda \int_0^{2 \pi} a^2 \cos^2 \theta+ b^2 \sin^2 \theta \, d\theta \\
&= \rho \pi a b \frac{a^2+b^2}{4}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your chain of equations for you. You can check the source to see how I did it.

Comment: That is really clever!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.  It's been a while since I've had to integrate anything nontrivial.